# Widespread misinterpretation of DNS rules in resolving wildcards

Tags: domain-name-system, wildcard

[EDITED to add: This problem has gone away on its own. I believe Cloudflare's name resolution may have been to blame. See my own answer below]

Here is a snippet of my zone file

```
*.example.com.      300 IN  CNAME   proxy.herokuapp.com.
foo.example.com.    300 IN  A       111.111.111.111
```

If I `dig @8.8.8.8 foo.example.com` I get the answer I expect:

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
foo.example.com.    30  IN  A   111.111.111.111
```

The same is true of all other public DNS servers I've tried.

However, when I try to set up a check with *Pingdom* to a URL on `foo.example.com` it instead sends the traffic to my Heroku app referenced by the `*.example.com` RR.

The same is true of checks set up on *New Relic*, *Errplane* and traffic generated by the *Heroku* app itself.

So on the one side, all public DNS servers interpret the zone file one way. Yet four service providers all interpret it a different way, one that differs to the standard suggested by RFC 4592.

My question is: are these reputable, mature service providers all wrong? Or is it little me?

Comment: any chance you could share the actual name?  It makes diagnosis a _lot_ easier!

Answer (score 2):

From a protocol standpoint, the *authoritative nameserver* synthesizes responses to queries that fall within a wildcard, not the servers that query it. If you are getting different responses, then one of the following has to be the case:

1. They are not talking to the same server. Either you have multiple auth nameservers and they are sending different responses, or a different set of auth servers are being consulted entirely. (does your company run a split DNS config?)
2. Some of the caching servers have an older record in cache.
3. DNS is being bypassed entirely, i.e. an entry in the hosts file.

Comment: 3a. A different type of RR is being requested (eg, AAAA)

Comment: @fukawi2 No, the authoritative server should attempt to resolve the name before it resolves the QTYPE.  If asked for `foo.example.com AAAA` it `MUST` return `NODATA` (i.e. RCODE 0, nothing in the Answer Section) because the specific _name_ does exist.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer, Andrew B. I don't think it's (1) because the only nameservers are run by Cloudflare. I don't think it's (2) because the problem persisted for many days. It's unlikely to be (3) because the problem affected several different services and I guess they wouldn't all bypass the DNS in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

After around 10 days the problem went away on its own. My best guess is that Cloudflare (who run the nameservers for this domain) changed its DNS resolution code.

Some more information:

1. Andrew B's answer (2) is a candidate: the name was being resolved by caching servers that hadn't been refreshed since I added the A-record. The problem persisted for more than a week so I don't believe this is likely.
2. I raised the issue with Cloudflare and it was escalated to the engineering team. They recently released some updated name resolution code (https://twitter.com/eastdakota/status/351733117003902976)

I think I understand how name resolution works a bit better than when I asked the question. It seems more likely that there was a single cause (Cloudflare bug) than multiple causes (separate bugs at Heroku, NewRelic, Pingdom & Errplane).